# Mary got a loan with a monthly fee of 1%, how much did she have after 6 months? Solving this problem 2 different ways.

Tags: finance

> Mary got a loan of 1000 euros. The institution that made the loan
>   charges a monthly fee of 1%.
>
> Because, in the following 6 months, Mary has done no amortization of
>   the loan, how much does she owe to the institution after those 6
>   months?

I could solve this problem 2 ways:

$$1000 \cdot e^{.01t} \approx 1061.84$$
or

$$1000 \cdot (1+.01)^6 \approx 1061.52$$

My book says the second one is correct, but since the values are so similar, are both solutions correct? If not, why?

Comment: Your first version uses what is called "continuous compounding", which I find confuses more people than it helps.  Your second answers the question, with $1\%$ compound interest each month.  They would be clearly different if you used a $100\%$ monthly interest rate: $1000 \times e^t$ compared with $1000 \times 2^t$

Comment: The first formula is for _continuous_ compounding interest. The second is for _discrete_ compounding interest, which is more appropriate for this scenario, because the fee is applied monthly. See [this](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/050115/what-difference-between-continuous-compounding-and-discrete-compounding.asp) for more info.

Comment: If the answers are close enough can you please send all math.SE users \$0.32. No bank in the world would say they are both correct.

Comment: @IanMiller You'd be surprised.

Comment: Let me change 'would' to 'should' then. Or at least no bank I'd trust my money with.